# What impersonator contracts does Racket have in addition to `new-∀/c` and `new-∃/c`?

Tags: racket, contracts

Racket [contracts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contracts.html) are classified in [three categories](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contracts.html#%28tech._flat._contract%29): Flat Contracts, Chaperone Contracts and Impersonator Contracts.

For Impersonator contracts, the only example I could find are the contracts for [parametric polymorphism](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/parametric-contracts.html). Are there any other examples in addition to these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object and class contracts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Object_and_Class_Contracts.html) (e.g., `class/c`, `object/c`, etc.) are currently all impersonator contracts. Though chaperone versions of those may be offered eventually. In contrast, it's not possible to make parameteric contracts into chaperone contracts.

Recursive contracts constructed with [recursive-contract](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contract-utilities.html?q=recursive-contract#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._recursive-contract%29%29) also default to impersonator contracts, but can be configured to be any type.